# Multiple conditions on SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, join

**tldr:**

I have a table A with a primary key `id`, and a table B with a foreign key that points to `A.id`

I want to select all A that contain a B. But not any B, only a B that has some condition**s** applied to it.

--

To give you an idea about the problem, let's say
my table A is `products`, and my table B is `features`.

I want to preform a search on the products, based on certain features.

My first approach was to join the table `features` multiple times with different aliases then apply one condition per alias. But I am pretty sure there is a more suitable way in term of performance to do this.

Would `GROUP BY products` and a single join be faster ?

Thank you for your consideration.

EDT: as requested in the comments, here is the data structure:

```
TABLE products
id (int 11)
name (varchar)
category (int 11)   fk->categories.id
description (mediumtext)
[...]

TABLE features
id (int 11)
name (varchar)
category (int 11)   fk->categories.id

TABLE products_features
id (int 11)
product (int 11)    fk->products.id
feature (varchar)   fk->features.id
value (varchar)

TABLE categories
id (int 11)
name (varchar)
```

Comment: you can do it in single join why to use multiple.and simply add the where clause required.

Comment: I want to select the products. i don't care about the features content, all I need is to perform conditions on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM products p 
JOIN features f ON p.id = f.pid
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN f.feature = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.feature = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Change `f.feature = 1` to appropriate predicate.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed